# How to add a Component in a Listcell?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, zk

I'm working in a java program using ZK platform. i have a Listbox and it has some Listcells. i want some Listcells to have a Textbox inside them but the constructors of Listcell just have Strings as input arguments and i can't put a Textbox in them. How can i add a component like Textbox in a Listcell ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the text box parent to your list cell like this:

```
public class ListItemRenderer implements ListitemRenderer,Serializable{

  @override
  public void render(Listitem item,Object data) throws Exception{
   ....
   Listcell lc=new Listcell;
   Textbox text=new Textbox();
   text.setParent(lc);
   lc.setParent(item);
   ....
}
....
}
```